# Mechanize complex form input name

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am trying to access a form in mechanize with ugly characters in the object name
similar to this

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page  = agent.get('http://domain.com)
form = page.forms[0]
form.ct600$Main$LastNameTextBox = "whatever"
page  = agent.submit(form)
```

The problem is the $ in the html name is messing with ruby.
Is there another method i could use ie:

```
form.element_by_name("ct600$Main$LastNameTextBox") = "whatever"
```

Unfortunately i cant change the html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never touched Ruby, but according to [the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/Form) (you did read the docs, right?),

```
form["ct600$Main$LastNameTextBox"] = "whatever"
```

should work.

Comment: Looks like the docs have moved: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/Mechanize/Form